# Execute a command in a script and store the result in a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, io

I'm trying to store the result of this command that is written in a script

```
ls -l /etc|wc -l
```

in a variable on another file.
To summarize, I have a script with that command and when I execute it, I want the result to be stored in a variable in another file.
Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: `var=$(bash file)`. Read about [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) in `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use temporary file (if possible).

This command:

```
ls -l /etc|wc -l > /tmp/myvar.txt
```

Another file:

```
myvar="$(cat /tmp/myvar.txt)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do so I'll give you two solutions.

If the command you mention is in some file `script_A.sh` and you want the results of that script stored in some variable `$var` when running some other script `script_B.sh`, randomir's solution is good. In script_B:

```
var=$(bash path/to/script_A.sh)
```

If what you're asking is to run `script_A.sh` and then have it *write* a new line to a file that would store the results to a value when you run `script_B.sh`, I suppose you could run something like:

```
result=$(ls -l /etc|wc -l)
echo "var=\"$result\"" > path/to/script_B.sh
```

or even replace a line in a script_B.sh that already exists:

```
result= $(ls -l /etc|wc -l)
sed -i "s|var=SOMEPLACEHOLDER|var='$result'|" path/to/script_B.sh
```

If the latter is what you want, though, can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish? There's probably a better way than what you propose.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use '> path/to/file' at the end of your command to redirect the output to a file (this will override the file content).

If you need another behavior, like append the content, you should use '>>' instead of '>'.

Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) for more details.